# How to select multiple separated files in Project view in IntelliJ IDEA without mouse?

Tags: intellij-idea

Suppose I have two files in my project and I want to move them using F6 to another package. In my case I want to move two qualifiers (EightDigits and ThirteenDigits) to qualifiers package. If they were next to one another I could use Shift + arrows to select multiple files. Nonetheless there are Main and NumberGenerator classes between. Any idea how to select them without mouse as presented on the screen below?

[image]

Comment: Did you get any further with this?

Comment: No, I still don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 14):

This problem can be fixed by turning off "Open files with single click" in the Project tab > Gear icon.

It might be a bug; not sure.

Answer (score 5):

1. Move to the first file (EightDigits) using the arrow keys
2. Hold down the CTRL key and use the arrow down key until you reach the second file (ThirteenDigits).
3. Release the CTRL key. At this point, the first file should be highlighted in a *filled* blue rectangle (same as when you click it with a mouse) and the second file should be highlighted with an *empty* blue rectangle (you never see that kind of highlighting when you use a mouse).
4. Press the SPACE key. Now both files are highlighted in a *filled* blue rectangle. It means they are both selected.

Answer (score -3):

1- Click the first file, then press and hold the Ctrl key.
2- While holding down the Ctrl key, click each of the other files you want to select.

Comment: Doesn't this answer need the mouse? The question says "without mouse..."

Comment: Even using a mouse, in Idea 2020.1 EAP it is impossible to do that :-)